# Dart: Parsing byte data to a string

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following code. What I am trying to do is parse BLE service data to get `EddyStone Namespace` and `InstanceID`. is parse byte data into a string.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:convert';

main(){
    var list = [0, 2, 46, 80, 128, 106, 163, 130, 85, 170, 217, 250, 42, 21, 78, 45, 0, 85, 0, 0];
    Uint8List serviceData = Uint8List.fromList(list);
    ByteData data = ByteData.sublistView(serviceData, 0, 10); //for namespace 10 byte  
    var abc = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

    var dta = utf8.decode(abc);
    print(dta);
}
```

i got following error on utf8.decode(abc);

```
Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 4)
```

Can anybody tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to convert that data into a string? It clearly isn’t textual data so it doesn’t really make sense

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, i just want to parse them to get Eddystone namespace and instance id as mentioned here https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/eddystone-uid

Comment: And for that you shouldn’t convert anything to a string. That link explains the data and it’s not textual.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Can you shed some light please.  i am actually new to dart.

Comment: It’s not really anything to do with dart. You have data and explanation what it is. If you want the namespace it’s the bytes indicated in the document. No strings or conversions needed

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen variable `list` is list of integer I get as service data right after scan.  BLE device's namespaces id and instance id are alphanumeric. So i have to do something with this `list` to get desired alphanumeric values. This is what I am trying to do.

Comment: they’re binary in this data. They may be represented as text in hex, so you’ll need to get the suitable part of data and then convert it to hex most likely. Not treat it as text directly

Comment: What string do you expect?  *Why* do you want a string?  I see nothing in the linked specification that indicates that the namespace and instance IDs should be human-readable strings.  AFAICT they're just lists of bytes.

Comment: @jamesdlin The scanresults in List of integers. And from there i have to extract Namespace id and instance id, both are alphanumeric. 
As described in https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/eddystone-uid

Comment: I said that I looked at that already. That page says nothing about them being alphanumeric. Again, if you believe that they should be, give examples of the strings you expect to get from given binary data.

Comment: @jamesdlin for example list mentioned in OP should return Namespace ID ` 00022E50806AA38255AA` and Instance ID `D9FA2A154E2D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it seems that you're asking for a *hexadecimal* representations for sequences of bytes.

Note that strings you expected in your comments for the "namespace" and "instance" IDs seem wrong.  It looks like you just converted the first 16 bytes of your `List`, but since your original `List` is 20 bytes, it seems like it's supposed to be the entire 20-byte Service Data Block.

From [the specification you linked to in your comments](https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/eddystone-uid), the "namespace" ID starts at offset 2 and is 10 bytes long.  The "instance" ID starts at offset 12 and is 6 bytes long.  Therefore, you must first extract those subsequences.  Once you have the desired sublist, you can use [`int.toRadixString`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/int/toRadixString.html) to convert each byte to a hexadecimal string, use [`String.padLeft`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/padLeft.html) to force using two hexadecimal digits, and then use [`List.join`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/join.html) to combine them all into a single `String`:

```dart
String getHexString(
  List<int> list, {
  required int offset,
  required int length,
}) {
  var sublist = list.getRange(offset, offset + length);
  return [
    for (var byte in sublist)
      byte.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0').toUpperCase()
  ].join();
}

void main() {
  var list = [0, 2, 46, 80, 128, 106, 163, 130, 85, 170, 217, 250, 42, 21, 78, 45, 0, 85, 0, 0];

  var namespaceId = getHexString(list, offset: 2, length: 10);
  var instanceId = getHexString(list, offset: 12, length: 6);

  print(namespaceId); // Prints: 2E50806AA38255AAD9FA
  print(instanceId); // Prints: 2A154E2D0055
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the offset, length for namespace and instance id should be `0,10` and '10,6' respectively

Comment: @WatsMyName I accidentally posted my answer prematurely.  See my updated answer (which also has an important correction for a typo in the code).

Comment: Thanks, why you've used  `padLeft(0, '2')`, this may not be needed?

Comment: @WatsMyName That was the typo.  I meant `padLeft(2, '0')`.